# HTML/CSS: Font-Awesome Icons Not Appearing

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

For some reason the font-awesome social media icons refuse to show up on any browser. All other icons seem to work perfectly fine though... I've included a photo of the page opened in Mozilla with inspect element(linked due to no reputation). The only loaded css files are bootstrap and awesome-font.

[image]

Comment: that's not very awesome.

Comment: can you post your `<link>` tags where you include both files?

Comment: Or even create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to isolate your problem?

Comment: Figured it out, I'm just an idiot and didn't set rel="stylesheet" so the only icons I could use are the default bootstrap. Thanks all

Comment: This showed up in related questions... if you're still looking for the solution see this answer I just wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812241/font-awesome-not-appearing-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you thought the text description of stacks was the class names. Icon stacks should look like this, there is no `on` class:

```
<span class="icon-stack">
    <i class="icon-minus icon-stack-base"></i>
    <i class="icon-camera icon-light"></i>
</span>
```

In your example, the second class overwrites the first class. This is because your using both classes on the same element, instead of stacking them.

Comment: Even with the added "on" class the icons should still load

Comment: @koala_dev In his example, the second class overwrites the first class. This is because he's using both classes on the same element, instead of stacking them.

Comment: I know, but even if he has "icon-camera on icon-minus" the minus icon should load, anyways the issue is now solved